# Adjust frame size to content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, size, pack

I need to set JPanel's preferred size so the pack() method of a JFrame component works fine. How can I set this size automatically? I have a JPanel with a GridLayout 3x3, filled with 9 ImagePanels:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;

    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is to get the size of this JPanel of images.

```
image.getWidth() * 3
image.getHeight() * 3
```

is not what I seek. I'd rather want to know something similar to pack().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to have the images determine the component's preferred size, something like this:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;

    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        // setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (image != null) {
            int w = image.getWidth();
            int h = image.getHeight();
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        } else {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
    }

    @Override   // this should be protected, not public
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank's for help and for the comments :)